# How to select a column from one table and two columns from another table when both the tables have no relation in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

I will explain my problem as simple as possible.
I have written a select query `Query1` on `Table1` which gives the me the following result

> SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE TypeID=1
>
> ID Column1 Column2 TypeID
>   1 A A 1
>   2 B B 1
>   3 C C 1

I have another table `Table2` which has data in the following format

> ID Column1 Column2
>   1 0 0
>   1 1 1
>   2 2 2
>   2 3 3
>   2 4 4
>   3 5 5
>   3 6 6

I have written a another select query `Query2` on `Table1` which gives the me the following result

> SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE TypeID=2
>
> ID Column1 Column2 TypeID
>   4 A A 2
>   5 B B 2
>   6 C C 2

`Table1` and `Table2` have no column in common and data in `Column1` and `Column2` for both `TypeID's` in `Table1` is same and currently data in `Table2` has data with values of `ID` column from `Table1` for id's 1,2,3 only and i want to write a select query to select same data from `Table2` but with values of `ID` column from `Table1` with `TypeID` as 2 which I have given below

> ID Column1 Column2
>   4 0 0
>   4 1 1
>   5 2 2
>   5 3 3
>   5 4 4
>   6 5 5
>   6 6 6

how can I achieve this by writing a select query in sql server?

Comment: Please define the exact logic of the desired results.

Comment: You've anonymised your sample data too far - at the moment, I'd just write a query `select 4 as ID, 0 as Column1, 0 as Column 2 union all select 4,1,1 union all select 5,2,2 ...` - you need to work on your sample data and/or explain the actual data and the desired relationships.

Comment: i have edited the question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select T1.column1, isnull(T2.column2,0) as column2,
 isnull(T2.column3,0) as column3
from table1 T1
left outer join on Table2 T2 on T1.column9=T2.column9
where ....
```

Comment: cant use joins or any equal condition as `Table1` and `Table2` has no common column

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the query whould be like that:

```
SELECT
  T_ID.T2_ID,
  Column1,
  Column2
FROM
  Table2
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      T1.ID AS T1_ID,
      T2.ID AS T2_ID
    FROM 
      Table1 AS T1
      JOIN Table1 AS T2 ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1 AND T1.Column2 = T2.Column2
    WHERE
      T1.TypeID = 1
      AND T2.TypeID = 2      
  ) AS T_ID ON Table2.ID = T_ID.T1_ID
```